# Will cyclopenta-2,4-dienecarbaldehyde undergo aldol condensation or cannizzaro reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, aldol-reaction

The following question was given in an exam.Which of the following undergo aldol condensation ?

Given answer :  a,b,c

[image]

My answer: b,c

My Logic :

Cyclopenta-2,4-dienecarbaldehyde(**1**) on reaction with a base gives carbanion whose resonance structures are **1a to 1e** as shown below.This anion is an aromatic anion .Being stable ,tis aromatic anion now in oresence of base would undergo Cannizaro Reaction to give **3 and 4**.

[image]

My question is, will cyclopenta-2,4-dienecarbaldehyde  undergo aldol condensation?

Comment: Well the CH group between 2 double bonds and a CHO group seems very "deprotonable" to me. But this is just to make your imagination "bubbling" !!

Comment: Hi, please don't make new tags - although this is something the system allows you to do with a handful of reputation, on Chemistry.SE we don't usually do this without some sort of consensus on Meta. In this case, there were already appropriate tags to describe your question well. If you're unsure you can always ask somebody what is a good tag. Also, *please* avoid the all caps.

Comment: Somewhat ambiguous in the wording of the question. Presumably, we're talking about self aldol?

Comment: Anyway, the only legitimate reference I can find to the starting material in the literature is this https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/jlac.19646780107, where it's made as a mixture of isomers/tautomers, so it seems that (as has been the case before) this is a made-up question which cannot be seriously answered. (Reaxys turns up a few more hits for the compound, which upon closer inspection are revealed to be typos.)

Comment: @orthocresol ,this question was given to students preparing for IIT engineering exam in my city during a weekend test.My point is ,since carbanion is involved in aromaticity, it would remain stable,and therfore may not participate as enolate. And there may no be an aldol.

Comment: I think the formation of an aromatic anion does increase the favourability of forming it, lowering activation energy of the 1st step of the reaction, allowing it to take place more quickly. But of course, it should not end there because there is additional stability to be gained from the aldol condensation. However, perhaps, the aldol may take take place at the alpha carbon and it may occur at another carbon in one of the other resonance structures, to allow for the elimination of water in the condensation.

Comment: @orthocresol ,I didnot know I created  a tag .I have no intention. Is there any  mechanism to untag, please let me know.

Comment: @Zhe , I edited the question.Which path will the molecule take,an aldol path or cannizzaro path , given ,the intermediate is aromatic. Would it loose aromaticity to again form energitically higher non aromatic species to give aldol or remain aromatic ,in which case lead to cannizzaro reaction  ?

Comment: @Tan Yong Boon , great idea.However , my point is , aromatic carbanion is stable , and therefore may not undergo self aldol.If carbanion occurs at different point ,then, this carbanion would loose aromaticity, in which , itwould be energitically be more abd aldol self condensation may not take place.